# How to make outer div grow or shink to the size of the inner div

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div and three inner divs each div is viewed separately and when each div is viewed i want the outer div's height to grow or shrink accordingly.

I wish to have tables inside each div which will expand dynamically this means they will not all be the same size, and I would like the outer div to match the size of the inner divs , thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div id="scroll-view">
    <div id="scroll-items">
        <div class="view"></div>
        <div class="view"></div>
        <div class="view"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="previous">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.view { width: 300px; height: 300px; float:left; }
#scroll-view {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;

    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#scroll-items { width: 10000px; max-height: auto;  overflow:auto; position: absolute ; }
```

Comment: You would want to use percentages for it to grow/shrink according to its parents' size.

Comment: what have you tried? what have you looked up? It seems that you haven't researched answers to your question very thoroughly.

Comment: I have tired using overflow:auto and min and max-height but no luck @SomekidwithHTML

Comment: The outer div will grow/shrink automatically to accomodate the content - just don't put a height on it

Comment: thats what it does not do @BillyMoat

Comment: @ShamariCampbell - Maybe just remove your height attributes from .view and from #scroll-view then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand the effect you're trying to achieve, it'd help if you could reword the question.

Having said that, is this close to what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/72deF/

Comment: Kind of yes but in mine what happens is that the outer div 'scroll-view' the height stays the same so its like a fixed height i just want it to grow and shrink accordingly @Josh

Comment: if you look at the code, there's no height defined on #scroll-view, it'll adjust accordingly. See http://jsfiddle.net/72deF/1/. Each .view has a different height and #scroll-view expands to hold the tallest of them.

Comment: if this answer has helped you please accept it so other people with similar issues know that this solution works.